# action bar sherlock guidelines needed

Tags: android

i'm trying to implement action bar in 2.3.3 version. As i'm new to android and engineering student i'm finding it difficult to implement it.I know action bar supported from 3.0. i've downloaded your library and imported inside my project. Still it is giving some error.I'm struggling to do this from many days. Please guide me properly how to achieve it . Is there any specific version of sherlock i've to download for 2.3.3.i've seen the video you uploaded in youtube. There your mentioning it for api level 13. So Please help me in this regard

Comment: what...? i have no specific idea what you're asking...

Comment: There is no action bar in 2.3.3 you'd have to add it... action bar is something from honeycomb.

Comment: how to add it..i tried with action bar sherlock library.. but getting error while importing

Comment: you need to be more clear in what you're asking. This is ambigious, you're obviously talking about a library..

Comment: how to add action bar in 2.3.3.pleaseprovide any link if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for support on the ActionBarSherlock library, I suggest you place your request using one of the requested methods on their support page.  Jake is on StackOverflow but that doesn't mean you will be lucky enough for him to stumble on this question.  You can find more information at:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/support.html

This page provides links to the Google Group, Github page, and direct contact information for the developer himself.  I would recommend that when you post your issue to these support channels, you provide some more specific information about the error you are receiving, with perhaps some snippets of your code.

HTH

Comment: [2012-01-26 11:26:29 - ActionBarCompat-DroidUX] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2012-01-26 11:40:48 - axn] C:\Users\kdr\Desktop\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-436230d\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-01-26 11:40:48 - axn] C:\Users\kdr\Desktop\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-436230d\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:48: - Getting this error while importing

Comment: Let me reiterate that you should post these questions on their support forum.

Answer (score 1):

I had errors on @Override methods because I was using Java 1.5. Switching to 1.6 solved them.

To do this : right click on your project > Properties > Java Compiler > Enable project specific settings > Compiler compliance level > 1.6

It is related to this issue in the project's bug tracker : https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/28